# Why does it take forever to run my python code even for a small input?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, and I am also new to this website. So sorry if my code is stupid, and I'm wasting your time. I have been trying to solve a Project Euler [Problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12). With a little help of internet I've come up with an algorithm and wrote a code in python. I've tried to generalise it so that it works for all numbers not only 500. At first I had problems with getting the right output, but then when I thought I fixed it, it only got worse because the program took forever to run. Could you point out the misstakes I've made:

```
L = int(input("L="))
def number_of_divisors(n):
    global divisors
    global count
    global p
    divisors = 1    
    count = 0
    if n%2 == 0:
        while n%2 == 0:
            count += 1
            n=n/2
       divisors = divisors * count
    count = 0
    p = 3
    while n != 1:
        while n%p == 0:
            count +=1
            n = n/p
        p += 2
    divisors *= (count + 1)
    return divisors
def the_first_triangular_number_with_more_than_L_divisors(L):
    global total_divisors
    global n
    total_divisors , n = 1 , 1
    while total_divisors <= L:
        s = number_of_divisors(n+1)
        total_divisors *= s
        total_divisors = s
    n += 1
    return (n*(n+1))/2
x = the_first_triangular_number_with_more_than_L_divisors(L)
print(x)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `total_divisors *= s` and then immediately `total_divisors = s`?

Comment: And why are you testing the number of divisors of `n`, instead of the `n`th triangular number? You really ought to carefully proofread your work.

Comment: I guess i forgot to use another variable there. I wrote total_divisors=s because s is the value for n+1 and that will be the value for n in the next step

Comment: Because nth triangular number equals n×(n+1) and it is easier to find the number of divisors for n+1 and then multiply by number of divisors of n which should be already known. These two numbers are consecutive so they don't share a common divisor

Comment: Are you expecting the `total_divisors <= L` condition to be continuously monitored, triggering an end to the loop even if it stops being true in the middle of the body? Loop conditions don't work like that.

Comment: why `global`?? looks like you use it to declare the variable, but in python the moment of the first assignation is also the the moment of declaration so that is not needed

Comment: I used it because it treated these variables as local and couldn't execute the code. It displayed error saying that local variable was referenced before the assingnment

Comment: in the code as you show it , removing the lines with `global` should not be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an infinite loop. If it enters the loop and s <= L, it will repeat indefinitely because of the last line (perhaps a typo).

```
while total_divisors <= L:
    s = number_of_divisors(n+1)
    total_divisors *= s
    total_divisors = s
```

Here is an answer that mirrors yours quite closely, you can take a look if you're completely stumped:

http://code.jasonbhill.com/sage/project-euler-problem-12/

Comment: I used the link you gave me to fix my code and it worked. Thank you very much!